# How to get minutes using SQL in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a result using SQL inside a function

```
select a[2] as hour, a[3] minutes from ( select regexp_split_to_array('for  7h 18m', ' ') ) as dt(a);
```

and i got result as

```
hour    minutes
7h       18m
```

I want to get

```
minutes
 438
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation has an [example](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html) using extract and epoch.

```
SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM '2h 18m'::INTERVAL)/60;
```

Comment: This is also awesome...Thanks

Answer (score 2):

One option here is to remove the `h` from the hours string, multiply by 60 to get minutes, then add this quantity to the minutes field, with the `m` removed.  Try this query:

```
select regexp_replace(a[2], '[h\s]', '')::integer * 60 +
       regexp_replace(a[3], '[m\s]', '')::integer as minutes
from
(
    select regexp_split_to_array('for  7h 18m', ' ')
) as dt(a);
```

Comment: getting error Error in query: ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: ""